# yii 2 wbraganca dynamic form actionCreate does not work

Tags: yii2

I tried to use wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform on my project everything is well done, but when I click on create button to validate actionCreate nothing happened.
project structure:
suppliers (sup_id, sup_name .....)
purchases(purchase_id,sup_id,purchase_date) sup_id is a foreign key
purchases_items(purchase_item_id,purchase_id,item_id,qte) purchase_id and item_id are foreign key
Items(item_id,......)
what I want to do is when user create a purchases, he will be able to create purchases_items at same, and after that update column stock from table items by incrementing with purchases_items's qte value of corresponding item_id .

NB: column stock is the stock level of items.
The project is about stock management.

```html
   _form.php


<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use dosamigos\datepicker\DatePicker;
use wbraganca\dynamicform\DynamicFormWidget;

//use yii\jui\DatePicker;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use backend\models\suppliers;
use backend\models\Items;




/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model backend\models\Purchases */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>

<div class="purchases-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'dynamic-form']); ?>

   
  
  <?= $form->field($modelPurchases, 'purchase_date')->widget(
        DatePicker::className(), [
            // inline too, not bad
             'inline' => false, 
             // modify template for custom rendering
            //'template' => '<div class="well well-sm" style="background-color: #fff; width:250px">{input}</div>',
            'clientOptions' => [
                'autoclose' => true,
                'format' => 'dd-M-yyyy'
            ]
    ]);?>
    
     <?= $form->field($modelPurchases, 'sup_id')->dropDownList(
        ArrayHelper::map(suppliers::find()->all(),'sup_id','sup_name'),['prompt'=>'Select Fournisseur']

    ) ?>

    <?= $form->field($modelPurchases, 'purchase_status')->textInput() ?>
    
    
    <!--purchase item information-->      
   
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading"><h4><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i> Contenu Achat</h4></div>
        <div class="panel-body">
             <?php DynamicFormWidget::begin([
                'widgetContainer' => 'dynamicform_wrapper', // required: only alphanumeric characters plus "_" [A-Za-z0-9_]
                'widgetBody' => '.container-items', // required: css class selector
                'widgetItem' => '.item', // required: css class
                'limit' => 6, // the maximum times, an element can be cloned (default 999)
                'min' => 1, // 0 or 1 (default 1)
                'insertButton' => '.add-item', // css class
                'deleteButton' => '.remove-item', // css class
                'model' => $modelsPurchaseItems[0],
                'formId' => 'dynamic-form',
                'formFields' => [
                    //'purchase_id',
                    'item_id',
                    'qte',
                
                ],
            ]); ?>
            <div class="container-items"><!-- widgetContainer -->
            <?php foreach ($modelsPurchaseItems as $i => $modelPurchaseItem): ?>
                <div class="item panel panel-default"><!-- widgetBody -->
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title pull-left">Contenu Achat</h3>
                        <div class="pull-right">
                            <button type="button" class="add-item btn btn-success btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></button>
                            <button type="button" class="remove-item btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <?php
                            // necessary for update action.
                            if (! $modelPurchaseItem->isNewRecord) {
                                echo Html::activeHiddenInput($modelPurchaseItem, "[{$i}]id");
                            }
                        ?>
                        <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-sm-6">
                             <?= $form->field($modelPurchaseItem, "[{$i}]item_id")->dropDownList(
           ArrayHelper::map(items::find()->all(),'item_id','item_name'),['prompt'=>'Select Articles']

       ) ?>
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-sm-6">
                             <?= $form->field($modelPurchaseItem, "[{$i}]qte")->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
                           </div>
                        </div><!-- .row -->
                    </div>
                 </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
            <?php DynamicFormWidget::end(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
       <?= Html::submitButton($modelPurchaseItem->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?> 
    </div>
    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
</div>
```

```html
 PurchasesController.php
<?php

namespace backend\controllers;

use Yii;
use backend\models\Model;
use backend\models\Purchases;
use backend\models\PurchasesItems;
//use backend\models\Items;

use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\web\Response;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;


/**
 * PurchasesController implements the CRUD actions for Purchases model.
 */
class PurchasesController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['POST'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Lists all Purchases models.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => Purchases::find(),
        ]);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Displays a single Purchases model.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new Purchases model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @return mixed
     */
    /*public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Purchases();
        $modelPurchaseItem = new PurchasesItems();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $modelPurchaseItem->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $model->save();
            $modelPurchaseItem -> purchase_id = $model->purchase_id;
            $modelPurchaseItem -> save();
            
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->purchase_id]);
        }

        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
            'purchaseItem' => $modelPurchaseItem,
        ]);
    }*/
    
     public function actionCreate()
    {
        $modelPurchases = new Purchases();
        $modelsPurchaseItems = [new PurchasesItems];
        if ($modelPurchases->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

            $modelsPurchaseItems = Model::createMultiple(PurchasesItems::classname());
            Model::loadMultiple($modelsPurchaseItems, Yii::$app->request->post());


            // validate all models
            $valid = $modelPurchases->validate();
            $valid = Model::validateMultiple($modelsPurchaseItems) && $valid;
            
            if ($valid) {
                $transaction = \Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();
                try {
                    if ($flag = $modelPurchases->save(false)) {
                        foreach ($modelsPurchaseItems as $modelPurchaseItem) {
                            $modelPurchaseItem->purchase_id = $modelPurchases->id;
                            if (! ($flag = $modelPurchaseItem->save(false))) {
                                $transaction->rollBack();
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if ($flag) {
                        $transaction->commit();
                        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $modelPurchases->id]);
                       
                    }
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    $transaction->rollBack();
                }
            }
       }
        return $this->render('create', [
            'modelPurchases' => $modelPurchases,
            'modelsPurchaseItems' => (empty($modelsPurchaseItems)) ? [new PurchasesItems] : $modelsPurchaseItems
        ]);
    }


    /**
     * Updates an existing Purchases model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->purchase_id]);
        }

        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Deletes an existing Purchases model.
     * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'index' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $this->findModel($id)->delete();

        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }

    /**
     * Finds the Purchases model based on its primary key value.
     * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return Purchases the loaded model
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    protected function findModel($id)
    {
        if (($model = Purchases::findOne($id)) !== null) {
            return $model;
        }

        throw new NotFoundHttpException(Yii::t('app', 'The requested page does not exist.'));
    }
}
```

```html
  create.php
  
  
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;


/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model backend\models\Purchases */

$this->title = Yii::t('app', 'Creer Achat');
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => Yii::t('app', 'Achat'), 'url' => ['index']];
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="purchases-create">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <?= $this->render('_form', [
        'modelPurchases' => $modelPurchases,
        'modelsPurchaseItems' => $modelsPurchaseItems,
    ]) ?>

</div>
```

```html
  Model.php

<?php

namespace backend\models;

use Yii;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;

class Model extends \yii\base\Model
{
    /**
     * Creates and populates a set of models.
     *
     * @param string $modelClass
     * @param array $multipleModels
     * @return array
     */
    public static function createMultiple($modelClass, $multipleModels = [])
    {
        $model    = new $modelClass;
        $formName = $model->formName();
        $post     = Yii::$app->request->post($formName);
        $models   = [];

        if (! empty($multipleModels)) {
            $keys = array_keys(ArrayHelper::map($multipleModels, 'id', 'id'));
            $multipleModels = array_combine($keys, $multipleModels);
        }

        if ($post && is_array($post)) {
            foreach ($post as $i => $item) {
                if (isset($item['id']) && !empty($item['id']) && isset($multipleModels[$item['id']])) {
                    $models[] = $multipleModels[$item['id']];
                } else {
                    $models[] = new $modelClass;
                }
            }
        }

        unset($model, $formName, $post);

        return $models;
    }
}
```

[create form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEDQ3.png)

Comment: Put `die('Inside actionCreate()');` at the top of the `actionCreate()` method, then click submit again... does it get into here, i.e. do you see the text "Inside actionCreate()"?

Comment: Thanks it works! I found my error, it was in controller i used id instead purchase_id.